# header gets smaller as you scroll - with the scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

There are plenty of tutorials to get a header's height to become smaller when you scroll down and get bigger when you scroll up past a certain point. I was wondering how to get the header's height to get smaller as soon as you scroll, but with the scroll. so if you stop scrolling before the animation is done, it stops as well...then when you resume scrolling up or down it resumes as well.

Here is a fiddle that doesnt work at all how I want but its the code I found to animate on scroll...

http://jsfiddle.net/A3XQG/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 

    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

    if( ( scrollPos === 0 ) && ( scrollState === 'top' ) ) {
        $('.header').stop().animate({height: '200px'}, 300);
        scrollState = 'scrolled';
    }       
    else if( ( scrollPos === 0 ) && ( scrollState === 'scrolled' ) ) {
        $('.header').stop().animate({height: '50px'}, 300);
        scrollState = 'top';
    }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can give ideas but I hope no one codes this all for you, given you haven't shown effort to code it yourself. The trick is to detect the window's scroll position it and change the height based off of that up to a specified minimum height or max scroll position

Comment: Why not bind the scroll position to the css 'top' property of .header?

Comment: Im not sure how to do that, but I have content that needs to stay in place so I really need to animate height. I just updated the fiddle to show I need the height to get smaller with scroll up to the point of the text, then stop until you scroll back up when height will get bigger with scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/A3XQG/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-complicating it. Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    $('.header').height(200 - (200 * $(this).scrollTop() / $('body').height()));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9tgDs/

Update: (cap shrinkage at 150px)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    var _height = 200 - (200 * $(this).scrollTop() / $('body').height());

    if (_height >= 150) {
        $('.header').height(_height);
    }
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/9tgDs/2/

Comment: Thank You very much. I knew I had to do a simple calculation but obviously didn't know what to calculate. 

I also just tried this on my own page which has lots of content and the header gets continuously smaller. How would I stop the height from getting smaller than say 250px?? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I added if( ( $('.header').height() > 150) ){ around your function but when it stops at 150, it wont continue to get bigger when you scroll back up...

Comment: Of course, because once that condition resolves to false, none of the sizing logic will be executed.

Comment: I just realized I could replace $('.header').height() > with (this).scrollTop() < and it works...thanks!