# Resizing menu on scroll event

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

this is an extension of this post:
[header gets smaller as you scroll - with the scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673625/header-gets-smaller-as-you-scroll-with-the-scroll?noredirect=1#comment34540887_22673625)

I added some code to get more of what I need but limited myself as well in the process. I need the height of the header to stop at 100px. I added

```
if( ( $('.header').height() > 100) ){
```

around the

```
$('.header').height(200 - (200 * $(this).scrollTop() / $('body').height()));
```

and while it stops at 100, it doesn't get bigger as you scroll back up again. I also am checking to see if the height is less than 100 to do an animation and it works, but I need to reverse that top animation as well when you scroll back up

http://jsfiddle.net/9tgDs/1/

Comment: See update below. I've improved your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, nowhere in your code you have an if statement for the current position of the scrollbar. So right now you are not detecting when the scrollbar is in a certain proximity to the top.

You could add something like this:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100)
{
    $('.header').height(200 + (200 * $(this).scrollTop() / $('body').height()));
}
```

Your total JavaScript would then look like this:

```
var moved = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    
    if( ( $('.header').height() > 100) ){
        $('.header').height(200 - (200 * $(this).scrollTop() / $('body').height()));
    }
    
    if( ( $('.header').height() < 170) && !moved){
        $('.header').animate({top:"-40px"});
        moved = true;
    }
    
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100)
    {
        $('.header').height(200 + (200 * $(this).scrollTop() / $('body').height()));
    }
    
    if( ( $('.header').height() > 170) && moved)
    {
        $('.header').animate({top:"0px"});
        moved = false;
    }

});
```

You can see this in action <kbd>[in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWPXC/)</kbd>.

Additionally, you might want to check out these tutorials instead of inventing the wheel yourself:

> - [How to create a resizing menu bar](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-a-resizing-menu-bar/)
> - [Animated Resizing Header On Scroll](http://www.callmenick.com/2014/02/18/create-an-animated-resizing-header-on-scroll/)

### Update

Your current code is kind of laggy because it uses height as a reference, not scroll.

Because the animations are triggered on scroll, and changing of the height is a nested side-effect, you can much better stick to the `scrollTop()` position as your primary input.

What I mean:

```
var moved = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    
    if( $(this).scrollTop() < 2000 ){
        $('.header').height(200 - (200 * $(this).scrollTop() / $('body').height()));
        
        if (!moved && $('.header').height() < 170)
        {
            $('.header').animate({top:"-40px"});     moved = true;  
        } else if (moved && $('.header').height() > 170)
        {
            $('.header').animate({top:"0px"});       moved = false;
        }
            
    }

});
```

As you can see from <kbd>[this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KUTGS/)</kbd>, **this code performs better!**